# Duplicate alias error with BigQuery connection to table with arrays

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Inside Google Data Studio (now called Looker Studio) I'm getting BigQuery error:

```
Query error: Duplicate alias **paid_per_stats** found at [line number]
```

I am connecting to a table with nested arrays - see schema snippet below. In the data studio BigQuery connector I create two alias (for period 1 and period 2), with distinct alias names. But when I create a calculated field in the report comparing fields from the two periods, the table fails to load giving the duplicate alias error.

**connector code:**

```
select 
a.period_start_dt = date(@p1) as is_p1,
case when a.period_start_dt = date(@p1) then a.paid_skus else null end as p1_paid_skus, 
case when a.period_start_dt = date(@p2) then a.paid_skus else null end as p2_paid_skus

from campaign_kpis a
where (a.period_start_dt = date(@p1) or a.period_start_dt = date(@p2))
```

**a.paid_skus has the schema:**

```
-- other stuff
period_start_dt date,
paid_skus array<struct<
    sku_id string,
    paid_per_stats array<struct<
        sample_dt date,
        kpi1 int,
        kpi2 int
        >>
    >>
```

**example calculated field:**

```
(sum(p1_paid_skus.paid_per_stats.kpi1)-sum(p2_paid_skus.paid_per_stats.kpis))/sum(p2_paid_skus.paid_per_stats.kpi1)
```

everything works fine if i don't use `p1` and `p2` in the same calculated field.
It's as if data studio isn't using the full path to the field as the alias, just the "last mile"
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At this point this appears to be a bug in the platform. I worked around the bug in the Data Studio connection sql, by unnesting the arrays and then renesting (using array_agg) to the original schema with a different name for p1 and p2 inner arrays. Gross but worked.